# JSONArray into 2d numpy array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, arrays

I have a json array in this format in PYTHON. How to make it to a  2d numpy array?

```
[{"z":1,"y":0.10000000149011612,"x":0.10000000149011612},{"z":0.6666666865348816,"y":0.10000000149011612,"x":0.20000000298023224},{"z":0.5,"y":0.10000000149011612,"x":0.30000001192092896},{"z":0.6666666865348816,"y":0.10000000149011612,"x":0.4000000059604645},{"z":0.3333333432674408,"y":0.10000000149011612,"x":0.5},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.10000000149011612,"x":0.6000000238418579},{"z":0.8333333134651184,"y":0.10000000149011612,"x":0.699999988079071},{"z":0.5,"y":0.10000000149011612,"x":0.800000011920929},{"z":0.5,"y":0.25999999046325684,"x":0.10000000149011612},{"z":0.5,"y":0.25999999046325684,"x":0.20000000298023224},{"z":1,"y":0.25999999046325684,"x":0.30000001192092896},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.25999999046325684,"x":0.4000000059604645},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.25999999046325684,"x":0.5},{"z":0.5,"y":0.25999999046325684,"x":0.6000000238418579},{"z":0.8333333134651184,"y":0.25999999046325684,"x":0.699999988079071},{"z":0.6666666865348816,"y":0.25999999046325684,"x":0.800000011920929},{"z":0.5,"y":0.41999998688697815,"x":0.10000000149011612},{"z":0.6666666865348816,"y":0.41999998688697815,"x":0.20000000298023224},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.41999998688697815,"x":0.30000001192092896},{"z":0.6666666865348816,"y":0.41999998688697815,"x":0.4000000059604645},{"z":0.5,"y":0.41999998688697815,"x":0.5},{"z":0.8333333134651184,"y":0.41999998688697815,"x":0.6000000238418579},{"z":0.8333333134651184,"y":0.41999998688697815,"x":0.699999988079071},{"z":0.5,"y":0.41999998688697815,"x":0.800000011920929},{"z":0.6666666865348816,"y":0.5799999833106995,"x":0.10000000149011612},{"z":0.6666666865348816,"y":0.5799999833106995,"x":0.20000000298023224},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.5799999833106995,"x":0.30000001192092896},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.5799999833106995,"x":0.4000000059604645},{"z":0.8333333134651184,"y":0.5799999833106995,"x":0.5},{"z":0.5,"y":0.5799999833106995,"x":0.6000000238418579},{"z":0.6666666865348816,"y":0.5799999833106995,"x":0.699999988079071},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.5799999833106995,"x":0.800000011920929},{"z":0.3333333432674408,"y":0.7400000095367432,"x":0.10000000149011612},{"z":1,"y":0.7400000095367432,"x":0.20000000298023224},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.7400000095367432,"x":0.30000001192092896},{"z":0.3333333432674408,"y":0.7400000095367432,"x":0.4000000059604645},{"z":1,"y":0.7400000095367432,"x":0.5},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.7400000095367432,"x":0.6000000238418579},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.7400000095367432,"x":0.699999988079071},{"z":0.1666666716337204,"y":0.7400000095367432,"x":0.800000011920929}]
```

The array look like: `([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])` Every json object is a []

Comment: What would the 2d array look like? An example would be nice. Downvoted for absolute lack of effort.

Comment: do you mean by like this [[2, 0],
   [3, 0],
   [3, 1],
   [5, 0],
   [5, 1],
   [5, 2]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, json_array is a list of dictionaries

```
m = np.zeros((len(json_array), 3))
for i, elem in enumerate(json_array):
    m[i,0] = elem['x']
    m[i,1] = elem['y']
    m[i,2] = elem['z']
```

Comment: I did this, why there's error??
myjson = json.load(sys.stdin)
 

p =  np.array(len(myjson), 3)
for i, elem in enumerate(myjson):
    p[i,0] = elem['x']
    p[i,1] = elem['y']
    p[i,2] = elem['z']

Comment: Error was in m-array definition